# Multiple Subscribers - only one event handler get called

Tags: nservicebus

I'm using NServiceBus 5.1.2 and I have a problem with events subscription:

I have 2 workers (QueryWorker and CommandWorker):

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Worker
{
    public void Customize(BusConfiguration builder)
    {
        var container = BuildContainer();

        builder.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(c => c.ExistingLifetimeScope(container));
        builder.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
        builder.UsePersistence<AzureStoragePersistence>();

        builder.Conventions()
            .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("ProjectName") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"))
            .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("ProjectName") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Events"))
            .DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("ProjectName") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("RequestResponse"))
            .DefiningEncryptedPropertiesAs(p => p.Name.StartsWith("Encrypted"));

        builder.RijndaelEncryptionService();
    }
    ...
```

Same configuration for both worker.
Beside that I have UnicastBusConfig in both workers:

`<UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Assembly="ProjectName.Security.Message"  Endpoint="CommandWorker" />
      <add Assembly="ProjectName.Examination.Message" Endpoint="CommandWorker" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>`

All works fine in case where CommandWorker publish events (from ProjectName.Security.Message or ProjectName.Examination.Message namepsace) and QueryWorker handle those events. Though I have problem when I want to handle same event published by CommandWorker in QueryWorker AND in CommandWorker (2 subscribers) - only one handler gets called and it seams to be random which one.

Am I missing something or misunderstood pub/sub functionality ? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you able to send us a small reproduction of this issue ? You can raise an issue in https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/new

Comment: After couple of hours of work probably yes :) But at first glance it seams to be a bug for You ?

Comment: I could not reproduce it with minimal example - all works as expected. Still have a problem though. I discovered one regularity - when CommandWorker gets XCommand I'm getting System.InvalidOperationException: No handlers could be found for message type: XCommand. Nonetheless command is handled as usual and one event handler is called. Sending XCommand second time result in same exception but calling second event handler. Any ideas what can be source of this exception ?

Comment: Are you able to send us your code ? You can send it to support